# MIssing Devise errors when securing Login view in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, https, devise, flash-message

I had to secure the login view (with the simple email/password form).

I'm using devise. The thing is the sign in error messages get lost somewhere (probably redirections from http to https I guess).

I tried to do the following on my application controller:

```
after_filter :set_devise_flash_messages, :if => :devise_controller?

def set_devise_flash_messages
    if resource.errors.any?
      flash[:error] = flash[:error].to_a.concat resource.errors.full_messages
      flash[:error].uniq!
    end
  end
  private :set_devise_flash_messages
```

but it's not working either.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This question does not provide valid code to reproduce any problem, and so I've voted to close it. Please provide that information to prevent this question from being closed.

Comment: Hm... well Im using a gem for the ssl securing. The code I posted is the only one related to my issue, that and the redirections between http and https. What else do you want me to post? @RyanBigg

Answer (score 0):

So, I was missing something.

I had secured the 'new' action for the devise/sessions controllers, but I wasn't securing the 'create' action. So that was causing the loss of flash messages (in between the re directions of that action's protocol).

Cheers!